# show the bottom most tick of y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The bottom most tick in the Y axis is not visible in the line chart I've created. The axis creation code is:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5)
    .innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);
```

[image]

The axis is ok, but I need to show the tick and text at the bottom most of the Y axis. What's going wrong here? [Here is the JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ssw5kc01/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`nice()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md#linear_nice) in the domain:

```
y.domain([
    d3.min(chartData, function(n) {
        return d3.min(n.values, function(d) {
            return d.value;
        });
    }),
    d3.max(chartData, function(n) {
        return d3.max(n.values, function(d) {
            return d.value;
        });
    })
]).nice();
```

Here is your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c8mjha3o/

Comment: But if you see the first chart in the fiddle, it's still not showing the bottom most tick with text. Maybe this is problem with the grid itself, but is there any solution to this? That I should always get the bottom most tick.

Comment: D3 axes are supposed to be dynamic. So, there is no easy solution to "always show the first tick". If you want, you can use `tickValues`: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickValues